# How do the icons next to files in VS Code Git panel affect git ops?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, the `git` tab lists files that've changed.

I've been using this tab to `commit`/`push` for awhile w/o incident, but today I noticed some files have a `U` (for `untracked`, per tooltip) and others have an `M` (for `modified`):

[image: files in VS Code git tab, each with either an 'M' or 'U' icon]

This is likely my lack of git expertise at work, but I can't deduce from [the VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol) how I should interpret these icons wrt my workflow.

When I commit, does the fact that some files are `untracked` affect my commit? If so, how?

My understanding was that `untrack`ed files don't get committed, but VS Code seems to treat both `tracked` and `untracked` the same (at least, in my limited usage of it).

Answer (score 0):

Only files that are tracked and have staged changes will be included in the commit.  Any files which are untracked wouldn't affect the commit in any way.  But if you have files that you never want to commit changes to, you probably would want to add them to your .gitignore.

There are also extensions that help you add files/folders to your .gitignore available from the Marketplace. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=codezombiech.gitignore

Comment: thanks Keif.  After I posted this I did a little testing.  I committed with 6 'modified' files and 5 'untracked' files--ie, I didn't stage the untracked files first.  I then checked it with a certain git client you may have heard of, and the commit indicated that all files were modified/added. After a little more checking, it looks like `VS Code` holds my hand a little, as the log reflects a `git add -A -- .` before the `git commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file - --all`.

Comment: (but seriously: I love GitKraken for letting me obviate so much of the git sausage factory. great app.)